# APP_INITIALIZER not calling factory method defined in app.module

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set up an APP_INITIALIZER to do two separate things before my app is initialised, the first is it makes a http call to retrieve a local appConfig file. The second is triggering a method to setup an SDK for a third party service.

I want both of these methods to be awaited so that they complete before the app starts properly, which is exactly what APP_INITIALIZER does anyway, so great.

However the method I am calling from the `useFactory` declaration never seems to trigger, it's almost like the whole APP_INITIALIZER process is being missed altogether.

I've basically followed this article to the letter: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-how-to-use-app-initializer/

I'm just wondering if I'm doing something wrong somewhere.

App.Module

```
export function initApp(appInitService: AppInitService) {
  console.log("InitApp called"); //This log never gets printed to console
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return appInitService.init();
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  entryComponents: [

  ],
  providers: [
    AppInitService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initApp,
      deps: [AppInitService],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

AppInitService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppInitService {

  constructor(private _configService: AppConfigService,
              private _splitService: SplitIOService) { }

  init(): Promise<void>{
    console.log("InitApp called");
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('Loading app config...');
      return this._configService.loadAppConfig().toPromise().then(() => {
        console.log('App config loaded.');
        console.log('Initing Split SDK...');
        this._splitService.initSdkAsync().then(() => {
          console.log('Split SDK inited.');
          console.log('initApp finished.');
          resolve();
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```
@angular-devkit/architect          0.803.17
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.803.17
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.803.17
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.803.17
@angular-devkit/core               8.3.17
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.17
@angular/cdk                       8.2.3
@angular/cli                       8.3.17
@angular/material                  8.2.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter   8.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   8.3.17
@schematics/angular                8.3.17
@schematics/update                 0.803.17
rxjs                               6.5.3
typescript                         3.5.3
webpack                            4.39.2
```

Comment: [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hn7kir?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Since `AppInitService` is provided in root, there's  no need to add it to the providers array

Comment: Oh fantastic, thank you. What exactly was I doing wrong? Was it just providing the `AppInitService` in the array that was causing the issue or was there something else?

Comment: @RafiHenig I've changed my code to match your in the stackblitz, however I have a promise in a service that is being called and returned from before the init() promise has returned, as a result I'm getting errors. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: @RafiHenig Also, if I replace my `useFactory` function with `useFactory: () => () => Promise.resolve(console.log("Called"))`, this function is never actually called. I never see "Called" in my logs, why isn't this being called?